# Redirect to default full URL with mvc3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-areas

I want to give the users a friendly URL, with the desired area, and whenever they enter it, the site is forwarded to the default controller/action., but I am having a real hard time figuring out how to do it.

Example: someone types `http://mySite.com/System` and the routing engine redirects to the complete default url `http://mySite.com/System/Auth/SignIn`

I tried this, but it isn't working

```
routes.MapRoute(
   "System",                                       // Route name
   "System/{controller}/{action}",                 // URL with parameters
   new { area = "System", controller = "Auth", 
   action = "SignIn", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

PS: as I am using areas, System in this case is the {area}, Auth is the {controller} and SignIn is the {action}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could use a `SystemController` at the root level of your application, of which the `Index()` action would simply redirect to /System/Auth/SignIn.

Comment: I also thought of this, but the problem is that **System** is an Area in this case, so this solution would only work if the URL was `http://mySite.com/System/System`, but that's not the desired url, unless there isn't any other solution

Comment: Then you just need a `HomeController` with an `Index` action in the route of your System Area.

Answer (score 0):

is there any Reverse Proxy Solution is the architecture which host your application ?